# How can I remarry after resetting Dawnguard DLC?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I reset my Dawnguard DLC. I've played Dawnguard against vampires and when I was finished with the main quest, I downloaded the Serana marriage mod from nexus and married her, but I decided on give Dawnguard another run.

So I turned it off and made a new save. I drop the ring of matrimony and everything that could connected me to Serana and this time I sided with the vampires. But when I finished the main quest and told Valerica she could return to the castle, which she did, I put the amulet of Mara on and tried to propose to Serana again. However, this time after the first question (if she had something on her mind), nothing more appeared. There was just one small message in the left corner stating that Serana is available for proposal.

I can't marry her or anyone else in Skyrim because the real question (if they're interested in me) never appears.

I already tried some console codes to try go around this situation and nothing. I downloaded a new mod for Serana and still nothing. I turned off/on the marriage mod and still nothing.
I played Skyrim for a while now and it's not the first time I try and marry someone, but this once it's killing me. Why can I not marry her? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to remarry if you use the console as it is explained here: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marriage

Select spouse.
Enter the following console commands:

```
removefac 51596
player.removefac C6472
resetquest 74793
resetquest 21382
setstage 74793 10
```

This should make you able to marry again after 24h (whether you've installed Dawnguard or not)

Comment: by anonymous: "this is the more 'safe approach, since it reset entirely the marriage process, but remeber that Serana is a non-marriable NPC, and sometimes the load order of the mods don't change this 'satatus', try to fix any mod conflict using BOSS then run the game"

Answer (score 0):

As I can remember, marriage isn't part of dawnguard. So the game will think that you're married, even if dawnguard is off. You should search for mod, that will allow you multiple marriage or that will restore state before marriage.